# React-Final-Form: Set initialValues from props, form state resets on props change

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I have a component, that takes a `balance` prop, and this balance prop can change over time.

I then have a React Final Form to send a transaction, with usual fields amount to send, receiver... And in my `validate`, I just check that the user has enough balance to send the transaction.

However, if my balance changes when the user is inputting something, then the whole form resets. How would you only reset part of the form state?

See this codesandbox for an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jn69xql7y3:

- input something
- wait 5s
- see that the form state is blank again

Answer (score 14):

I just ran into this issue with `react-final-form` where the form completely resets when any state change happens in a wrapping component.

The problem is here (from your codesandbox)

```
<Form
  initialValues={{ amount: 0, balance }} <-- creates a new object on every render
```

The problem is that when `initialValues` changes the entire form reinitialises. By default, whatever you pass to `initialValues` is compared against the previous one using **shallow equals**, i.e. comparing reference.

This means that if you create a new object in the render, even if it's the same, the entire form resets when some state changes, the render function re-runs, and a new object with a new reference is created for `initialValues`.

To solve the general problem, if you just want to turn off the form resetting, what I've done is just move my `initialState`, which never changes, out to a variable so that it's the same reference on every render and therefore always appears to be the same to final-form with the default behaviour. I would prefer a configuration to actually completely turn off this reinitialisation behaviour, but I can't find one in the docs.

However if you actually want this, but need to modify it, the comparison behaviour can be configured using the `initialValuesEqual` prop ([docs here](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FormProps)), to do a deep comparison on the `initialValues` object for example.

You can also use the `keepDirtyOnReinitialize` prop to only reset the parts of your form that haven't been touched.

I would guess some combination of the above might solve your usecase, depending on the exact UX you need.

Answer (score 11):

Adding onto what @davnicwil mentioned, my solution is `useMemo()` hook in func components:

```js
const initialValues = useMemo(() => ({ amount: 0, balance }), [])
```

By using `useMemo` it creates only 1 object during the life of the component and subsequent re-renders don't cause initialValues to overwrite the form values.

Comment: This works for me too. Although I think this should eventually probably happen internally in the library. As I think an initialValue should not be used after the first render.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to use react-final-form Form prop `initialValuesEqual={() => true}`

```js
<Form initialValues={{ amount: 0, balance }} initialValuesEqual={() => true} .../>
```

ref: https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/issues/246