# How properly connect react-final-form and material-ui-chip-input?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, react-final-form

I'm using material-ui-chip-input wrapped with Field react-final-form.
[image]

I wanted to limit "CHIPS" to 5 only.

> Chips are compact elements that represent an input, attribute, or
> action.

[material ui docs](https://material-ui.com/components/chips/)

As you can see I'm using 2 states here

1. react useStates
2. react-final-form internal states

This is redundant because react-final-form handled states internally but I can't make to work I'm just showing what I have done so far.

Basically there are
two problems with my implementation.

1. It doesn't limit my chips.
2. My react-final-form field values - not updating when clicking DeleteChip

```js
import ChipInput from 'material-ui-chip-input'
import { Field } from 'react-final-form'

const [state, setState] = useState([])

const AddChip = useCallback(
    (chip) => {
        if (state.length + 1 <= 5) {
        setState((prev) => ([...prev.tags, chip]))
        }
    },
    [setState, state.length]
)

const DeleteChip = useCallback(
    (chip) => {
        setState((prev) => (...prev.state.filter((p) => p !== chip)]
        }))
    },
    [setState]
)

  return (
    <Field name="states" validate={isRequired} >
          {({ input: { value, onChange, ...rest }, meta }) => {
     <ChipInput
        defaultValue={Array.isArray(value) ? value : []} // check value first because material-ui-chip-input require an array, by default react-final-form value is empty string
        onChange={(event) => {  // uncontrolled 
            AddChip(event)
            onChange(event)
            // I tried below code but same result not working
            // if (state.length + 1 <= 5) {
            //  onChange(event)
            // }
        }}
        onDelete={DeleteChip} 
       />
      }}
    </Field>
  )
```

[material-ui-chip-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-chip-input)

[react-final-form](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/getting-started)

[see codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-worker-qqhb3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Could you provide us with a minimal version on some platform like codesandbox?

Comment: Ok, let me make one.

Comment: @Dom here https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-worker-qqhb3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my take:
https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-water-xp2y1?file=/src/App.js

Key points:

- Don't duplicate the state, let react final form handle the state for you
- Pass an empty array as the initial state to the FORM, don't pass defaultValues to the Field.
- according to the `material-ui-chip-input` package you need to use `onAdd` if used in controlled mode, which we do, since we let react final form handle the state.
- Add the `value` prop to the Chipinput.
- For cosmetic reasons: don't actually use the render-prop inside `<Form />` - use a functional child component instead.

Code:

```
import ChipInput from "material-ui-chip-input";
import { Form, Field } from "react-final-form";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Form
      initialValues={{
        states: []
      }}
      onSubmit={() => console.log("submitted")}
    >
      {({ values, onSubmit }) => (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <Field name="states">
            {({ input: { value, onChange } }) => (
              <ChipInput
                value={value}
                alwaysShowPlaceholder={true}
                placeholder="type states here"
                onAdd={(newVal) => {
                  if (value.length >= 5) return;
                  const newArr = [...value, newVal];
                  onChange(newArr);
                }}
                onDelete={(deletedVal) => {
                  const newArr = value.filter((state) => state !== deletedVal);
                  onChange(newArr);
                }}
              />
            )}
          </Field>
          <p>react useStates</p>

          <p>react-final-form values</p>
          <pre
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
              padding: "20px"
            }}
          >
            {JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2)}
          </pre>
        </form>
      )}
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's correct no need to use useState because react-final-form handle state internally. Your demo is great, problem with mine is I don't want to put intialValue on the <Form>.  I added defaultValue on <Field> got infinite loop.instead.

Comment: Here's my work around instead. Remove defaultValue from <Field /> props then in my value is  value={isEmpty(value) ? [] : value}

Comment: why do you not want that on the Form? That's the intended use for this

Comment: I'm working on wizard style form like in the demo of react-final-form but in materia-ul stepper implementation.  I have multiple screens each screen react-final-form saved the values from each fileds but when moving next page the values are gone.  So yeah, that's why I not initializing default values in the <Form /> itself.

Comment: I think this post is helpful regarding [initialValues is resetting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54635276/react-final-form-set-initialvalues-from-props-form-state-resets-on-props-chang)

Comment: can help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66168054/react-final-form-multiple-wizard-screen-next-button-and-form-validity-is-alwa